# How to make a promise object immutable when setting different states in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, redux, promise, react-redux, immutable.js

I'm working with React/Redux and want to use the same Promise result to set two different states. Here's my code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then((resp) => {
      Object.freeze(resp);
      const var1 = resp[0];
      const var2 = parseData(resp[0]);
      props.setAction1(var1);
      props.setAction2(var2);
    });
  }, []);
```

The content of `resp` is an array of dicts:

```
Array [ (95) […] ]

0: Array(95) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
​
0: Object { date: "6/1/11", open: 21.45673929 }
​​
1: Object { date: "6/2/11", open: 21.02743338 }
​​
2: Object { date: "6/3/11", open: 20.64964196 }
​​
etc...
```

I know that in Javascript object are mutable, so I attempted to make `resp` immutable with `Object.freeze(resp)`. `var1` should be the result with string dates and `var2` should be the result with date converted to `Date` objects with the `parseData` function, whose content is:

```
function parseData(data) {
  data.map((x) => (x.date = new Date(x.date)));
  return data;
}
```

My problem is that, when I run this function, `var1 === var2`. The `parseData` function affected not only `var2` but also `var1`. I don't understand how this happens, especially as I froze the `resp` object. This is likely an issue with immutability, but I'm unsure where else to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `Object.freeze` is what you're looking for. In the end, the objects still reference the same location in memory, even if they are frozen. You should make a copy of the data to separate the two so you can alter either of them without affecting the other one.

```
fetchData().then((resp) => {
  const ref1 = resp;
  /* Alternatively you can also use `Object.assign` */
  const ref2 = [ ...resp ].map(obj => ({ ...obj }));
}
```

Like @JohnD mentioned, you can also do that in your `parseData` function which might be a little tidier. ;)

Comment: There is no need for `[...resp]` when you already do `.map`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `parseData` function currently returns the same array object, in which the objects were mutated. If you want your objects to be immutable, you should not have code like `x.date =`. Instead do this:

```
function parseData(data) {
    return data.map((x) => ({...x, {date: new Date(x.date)} }) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe `Object.freeze(resp);` will freeze nested objects. You could try the following, but I believe it is confusing to read.

```js
useEffect(() => {
    fetchData().then((resp) => {
      Object.freeze(resp);
      Object.freeze(resp[0]);
      const var1 = resp[0];
      const var2 = parseData(resp[0]);
      props.setAction1(var1);
      props.setAction2(var2);
    });
  }, []);
```

Alternatively, you could change your `parseData` function to return a copy using the spread operator:

```js
function parseData(data) {
  [...data].map((x) => (x.date = new Date(x.date)));
  return data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Object.freeze will freeze the direct properties of the object you pass. It will not do this recursively, so giving it an array or nested object will not do what you expect.

> The `parseData` function affected not only `var2` but also `var1`.

No. Here, `var1 === var2` because your `parseData` code does not modify the object at all, but only a single property of it. It's the same object instance all-along. When you set `x.date = new Date(x.date)`, the `x` itself does not change.

Not sure if that's going to be necessary, but you could freeze each individual object in `resp`, using `map()`.

```
const freezeAll = items => items.map(item => Object.freeze(item));
const parseData = items => items.forEach(item => item.date = new Date(item.date));

// fetch data, process, and cache it
const data = fetchData().then(parseData).then(freezeAll);

// use data
useEffect(() => {
  data.then(items => {
    props.setAction1(items[0]);
    props.setAction2(items[0]);
  });
}, []);
```